# How do I change multiple linux servers' /etc/fstab simultaneously

Tags: linux, cluster, fstab, renderfarm

We have plenty of linux server that will mount a few linux file server by NFS or SMB using `/etc/fstab`

But manually changing each server's `/etc/fstab` is very tedious.

Is there any way to edit multiple linux server's `/etc/fstab` simultaneously?

Comment: What is your window for 'simultaneous' ?

Comment: Yes that's called centralized configuration management and/or orchestration.

Comment: i think webmin can do this, using cluster tab from gui

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long term, this is the sort of tasks that configuration management tools (e.g., `puppet`, `chef`, `ansible`) are made for.

For a short term solution, I'd use something like `func` or `fabric` to push out your `fstab` file. Going to run through an example of using `fabric` since that's the one I'm most familiar with.

Installation depends on your distro. One of these is likely to work:

```
$ sudo pip install fabric
$ sudo easy_install fabric
$ sudo apt-get install fabric
```

Then, you'll also need to distribute ssh keys. It's simple:

```
$ ssh-keygen
$ ssh-copy-id host2
$ ssh-copy-id host3
```

Now, you'll need to create a `fab` file (pretty much a `Python` script). For example, `copy_fstab.fab` would look something like this:

```
from fabric.operations import put
from fabric.operations import sudo

def copy_fstab():
    # Copy local fstab over
    put('/etc/fstab', '/etc/fstab', use_sudo=True)

    # Run mount -a
    sudo('mount -a')
```

Finally, you run the fab file:

```
$ fab -H host2,host3 copy_fstab
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This replaces your whole file. I wouldn't do that. Why would I want custom stuff like that, one file per server, in a mass deployment tool? Is that what this does? I strongly prefer a thing like fstab.d (which doesn't exist) to allow having just one small addition.

Comment: Agree with Peter; this is going to be painful with local disks even using device nodes rather than UUIDs.

Comment: I would rather deploy something like Puppet frankly. But if it's a one time sync, creating a `fab` with some `sed` commands and such would get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Using a mass deployment tool like automateit, salt, puppet, ansible, etc. you could run a script (in puppet use exec) or a cronjob like below to use mount to run a mass deployed fstab:

```
mount -a --fstab pathtofile
```

And my old answer (if your mount is too old to have --fstab / -T):
in such a mass deployment tool, you could do some terrible hackery to emulate an /etc/fstab.d behavior (since /etc/fstab.d is not yet supported, and those directories make deployment tools very useful).

Move fstab to /etc/fstab.d/01main

Deploy your fstab line in a file /etc/fstab.d/02nfsstuff

Merge them (here the number order is important):

```
cat /etc/fstab.d/* > /etc/fstab
```

Make a horrible hackjob cronjob in /etc/cron.d/nfsstuff

```
0 * * * * root cat /etc/fstab.d/* > /etc/fstab ; mount -a
```

I hope you find a proper solution, but until then, maybe this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Peter that using a deployment tool is the neatest solution. However I disagree that mouning stuff from cron is ever a good idea!

If the deployment tool is too much of a leap, I'd go with a late init/systemd script (which might fetch the definitions from a central respository) and mount the filesystems.

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea ;) I just said it was a hackish idea. And I provided it despite that because there is no fstab.d or equivalent, so I'm sure there will be no perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I have an admin account on each server available via SSH with public-key auth, I would simply remotely run sed or other text editing tool using this SSH account, in a bash loop.